# How to get email address from Azure AD B2C authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get Azure AD B2C to get the users email address but I don't see anything in the token that provides it, even though my signin/signup policy makes a "claim" on the users email address.  How do you do I get the email address?    More generally, is there any documentation other than the samples that explains how this service is intended to work?

Comment: what is A2BC?  Do you mean Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under application claims, check `Email Addresses`.

[image: select application claims]

Here's some [documentation about selecting claims/setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy).

Comment: Setting up the claim isn't the problem- I've done that part.   What I can't manage is how to get the users email address in my mobile app.   So far as I can tell the token returned to the app after login doesn't contain it, and I can't find the method used to interrogate active directory  for claimed attributes

Comment: if you've configured like the above then it must be in the claims assuming they have an email address filled out; have you viewed the user properties in the portal to verify this?

Comment: I think you might be missing the question.  I've checked the portal and it looks like the claim for email address is set up properly for my signin/singup policy. I authentical using MSAL (Microsoft Identity Client for Active Directory) which  returns an "AuthenticationResult"  and from what I can see there is no property of AuthenticationResult object which contains the email address (or any other attribute) I claimed in the portal.

Comment: I see, so you're asking how do you access them in MSAL.  [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773234/getting-azure-b2c-signupsignin-application-claims-using-msal-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Yes exactly.  Thanks for leading me to this post.